# In field controlled dc motor, why does the armature current remain unchanged even if it is affected by field flux?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

Basically in a field controlled dc motor, the armature current is kept constant (via some constant voltage source) while the field current is varied which will vary the field flux and interacts with the armature of motor and produce rotation. But why does the armature current not change when flux interaction is there with the armature and voltages are  flowing around the motor. How does the armature current remain constant. Does the speed of rotor changes to bring the armature current back to the constant value?? What causes the armature current to not change from its constant value?

Comment: The armature current doesn't change because it's supplied by a constant current source.

Comment: But for instance assuming that the constant current source supplies 5A and now the field flux acts on the armature and armature current rises due to the field flux and now assume it is 7A. So the armature current is not constant now. So how is this problem countered

Comment: If the current changed from 5A to 7A, it wouldn't be constant, would it? Constant current means the current is fixed! The current cannot vary from it's set value, no matter how the load changes. So the armature flux will be a constant magnitude no matter what happens to the flux generated by the field windings.

Comment: It may help if you first consider a constant voltage source of, say, 10V. If a \$100\Omega\$ resistor is connected across the source the current is \$0.1A\$; if a \$1\Omega\$ resistor is connected the current is \$10A\$. So the voltage is constant regardless of the load current. Now consider a constant current source of, say \$5A\$. If a \$1\Omega\$ resistor is connected the current will be \$5A\$ and the voltage across the resistor will be 5V; if a \$100\Omega\$ resistor is connected the current will be \$5A\$ and the voltage will be 500V. So the voltage varies to maintain the rated current.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does the speed of rotor changes to bring the armature current back to
> the constant value?? What causes the armature current to not change
> from its constant value?*

If you have an external field winding that controls the magnetic field of a DC motor, then a higher magnetic field means that the armature's back emf equalizes when the speed is lower. This is the criteria for stabilization of speed.

If the back-emf is too low then the motor armature speeds up until the constant applied armature voltage and the back-emf are at the right level to permit the right amount of armature current needed to generate mechanical power to the load and against friction.

It's all embedded in Faraday's induction equation: \$\text{emf} = -N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$. In other words, to make emf the right value to drive load and friction, the motor can run slower when the flux is higher because, what is lost in the rate of change of flux is regained by the flux actually being higher.